# How to change contour colors in a range of values

Tags: python, matplotlib

Colormap class in matplotlib has nice methods `set_over` and `set_under`, which allow to set color to be used for out-of-range values on contour plot.

But what if I need to set color to be used in a range of values, e.g. white out values from -0.1 to 0.1? Is there a method `set_between(colormap, interval, color)`? If not, what would be the easiest solution?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the NumPy where function to replace values in a specified range to the overall maximum or minimum value, and that would effectively whiten or blacken those values in your plot.

```
q = np.random.normal( 0, 1, (10,10) )
np.where( ( q > -.1 ) & ( q < .1 ), np.max( q ), q )
```

Comment: This will white out out of range values too, not just in specified interval.